# React Material UI CardHeader title overflow with dots

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

How can I properly add dots the the title in my Cardheader if it exceeds the parents width (Card width). So far I have done this:

```
  card: {
    width: 275,
    display: "flex"
  },

  overflowWithDots: {
    textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
    whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
    overflow: 'hidden',
    width: '100px'
  }

  <Card className={classes.card}>
    <CardHeader
       title={
         <Typography gutterBottom variant="h6" component="h4" className={classes.overflowWithDots}>
        {movie.title}
        </Typography>
       }
   />
```

This works in a way, but I have to tell the class to have a width of 100px until it adds the dots. I need to add the dots if it exceeds the parents width.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Problem

As I understand it you are limiting the size of the **Card**, in this case, you are not being able to place the ellipsis due to the way the **CardHeader** is rendered in the html.

The **CardHeader** component is rendered with a "**root**" element and a "**content**" element. See below:

[image: CardHeader rendered]

***Typography*** has a built-in prop to adding dots **noWrap**. For the **noWrap** property to work correctly, we have the following approaches.

#### Solution 1

CardHeader's default behavior is to use flex. If you don't need it use flex:

```
...

cardHeader: {
  display: "block",
  overflow: "hidden"
}

...

<CardHeader
  className={classes.cardHeader} 
  title={
        <Typography noWrap gutterBottom variant="h6" component="h4">
           A world wide web - the revolution
        </Typography>
        }
/>
...
```

#### Solution 2

If you need to keep CardHeader with flex behavior, in this case, the ***overflow*** needs to be applied to the ***root*** and ***content***. To reach the elements use the [CardHeader classes property](https://material-ui.com/api/card-header/#props) passing the generated class to the content prop.

```
...

cardHeaderRoot: {
  overflow: "hidden"
},
cardHeaderContent: {
  overflow: "hidden"
}

...

<CardHeader
  classes={{
           root: classes.cardHeaderRoot,
           content: classes.cardHeaderContent
         }}
  title={
        <Typography noWrap gutterBottom variant="h6" component="h4">
           A world wide web - the revolution
        </Typography>
        }
/>

...
```

Here's an example in the sandbox.

[image: Edit Button]

### Atention

*Be aware that by modifying the default behavior of how components are rendered, some side effects may occur in your entire component tree.*

#### Anyway

If you still have any problems let us know.

Comment: You example works, I may case it did not. So I tried working around a little and it is due to `display: flex` which I have in my card. Is there a way to accompish this with flex aswell? It looks like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/overflow-nbw1c) using flex.

Comment: That way you have to ensure that the overflow is applied to the entire flex tree. So apply overflow: hidden to your CardHeader root. Like this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/overflow-2xssh)

Comment: If you don't need the standard CardHeader behavior as flex this can also serve you by [removing the standard CardHeader flex](https://codesandbox.io/s/overflow-16y0t), use the technique that best suits your components. @user13262487

Comment: Thanks alot so by using root: and content: I can overwrite the default behavoir for this specific component?

Comment: Yes. I stepped up the answer. if you still have questions about this topic let us know.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you.  For both having the correct answer and writing it so clearly.

Answer (score 10):

Although [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61681409/13946081) solution works, if you are using mui v5, this is how you can do it using the `sx` prop described [here](https://mui.com/system/basics/#the-sx-prop). You can set the `.MuiCardHeader-content` style and `titleTypographyProps` prop to style the title. I added an action button and subheader as an extra example.

```
import React from "react";
import { Card, CardHeader, IconButton } from "@mui/material";
import { MoreVert as MoreVertIcon } from "@mui/icons-material";

const SimpleCard = () => (
  <Card sx={{ width: "275px", display: "flex" }}>
    <CardHeader
      sx={{
        display: "flex",
        overflow: "hidden",
        "& .MuiCardHeader-content": {
          overflow: "hidden"
        }
      }}
      title={"A very long title coooooooooooooool"}
      titleTypographyProps={{ noWrap: true }}
      subheader={"ps long subheader cooooooooooooool"}
      subheaderTypographyProps={{ noWrap: true }}
      action={
        <IconButton>
          <MoreVertIcon />
        </IconButton>
      }
    />
  </Card>
);

export default SimpleCard;
```

Here's the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/overflow-forked-5nio1?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) to mess around with.

Comment: You saved my day. Thank you!

As a side note: we can shorten the `sx` part down to `sx={{ "& .MuiCardHeader-content": { overflow: "hidden" } }}` .

Answer (score 1):

Typography has a built-in prop to adding dots. You can simply add noWrap prop to Typography. It will add dots in header text and according to the parent component width.

```
<Card className={classes.card}>
  <CardHeader
    title={
      <Typography gutterBottom noWrap variant="h6" component="h4">
        {movie.title}
      </Typography>
    }
  />
/>
```

Comment: it exceeds the width